# Can WPF window contain a child ?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF window:

```
<Window x:Class="Snapit.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" WindowState="Maximized"
    ShowInTaskbar="True" AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None" Opacity="0.1" 
    BorderThickness="25" BorderBrush="Black" Name="myWindow">
<Grid Name="myGrid">

</Grid>
</Window>
```

And I have a rectangle

```
System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle myRect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
        myRect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
        myRect.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Yellow;
        myRect.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
        myRect.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        myRect.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        myRect.Height = 50;
        myRect.Width = 50;
        myRect.Opacity = 100;
        myWindow.AddChild(myRect);
```

But I am not able to add the rectangle as a child and the error come as :

```
{"'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Snapit.MainWindow' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.' Line number '3' and line position '9'."}
```

I dont understand where I am going wrong. Thanks!!

Comment: Add rectangle as grid child. Window has already one child i.e. Grid. `myGird.AddChild(myRect);`.

Comment: You have to add it to `myGrid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your window can have only one child, and it's your Grid...
If you want to do it, you should change

```
myWindow.AddChild(myRect);
```

to

```
myGrid.AddChild(myRect);
```

But, why didn't you use the xaml to write your rectangle ? It will be more clean to read it...

Comment: The reason I used C# to create the rectangle is that I would be changing its dimensions based on the mouse drag movement. Would that be possible to change the XML with the changing mouse coordianates ?

Answer (score 1):

Add it to your Layout **Grid** not to Window,

Change this line,

**From** :`myWindow.AddChild(myRect);`

**To**   :`myGrid.AddChild(myRect);`

**Final Code:**

```
        System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle myRect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
        myRect = new System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle();
        myRect.Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Yellow;
        myRect.Fill = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;
        myRect.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        myRect.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        myRect.Height = 50;
        myRect.Width = 50;
        myRect.Opacity = 100;
        myGrid.AddChild(myRect);
```